# Php apply function in array if next entry is integer (Concatenate a valid FEN string)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, chess, fen

Trying to build a valid [FEN string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation).

Given this 8*8 array example, symbolizing a checker board, ("1" are empty squares):

```
$checkerboard = [["r","n","b","q","k","b","n","r"],["p","p","p","p","p","p","p","p"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","P","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["P","P","P","P","1","P","P","P"],["R","N","B","Q","K","B","N","R"]]
```

In situ, this is the position:

[image]

The valid result I am looking for is:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR
```

And by now my output is:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/11111111/11111111/1111P111/11111111/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR
```

Obviously, any integer entry in the array should be sum to the next, only if the next entry is an integer, and if so the next entry  should be discarded **till the end**.

By iterating the array, I am not sure how to apply something like [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) here in a simple way. Maybe a simple string operation is enough?

```
  $FEN = "";
  for ($i = 0;$i < 8;$i++){
    for ($j = 0;$j < 8;$j++){
      if ($checkerboard[$i][$j] === "1"){
        if ($checkerboard[$i][$j + 1] === "1"){
           /* How to iterate till the end */
           $FEN .= (int)$checkerboard[$i][$j] + (int)$checkerboard[$i][$j+1];
        }
      } else {
        $FEN .= $checkerboard[$i][$j];
      }      
    }
    $FEN .= "/";
  }
```

Any insights?

**Example online:** https://3v4l.org/tuqqo

Comment: what is `$F` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$checkerboard = [["r","n","b","q","k","b","n","r"],["p","p","p","p","p","p","p","p"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","P","1","1","1"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["P","P","P","P","1","P","P","P"],["R","N","B","Q","K","B","N","R"]];

$parts =  array();
foreach ($checkerboard as $innerArray) {
    $num = null;
    $str = '';
    foreach($innerArray as $innerval){
        if(is_numeric($innerval)){
            $num += (int) $innerval;
        }
        else{
            if(!is_null($num)){
                $str .=$num;
                $num = null;
            }
            $str .=$innerval;
        }
    }
    if(!is_null($num)){
        $str .=$num;
    }
    array_push($parts,$str);
}
$result = implode('/',$parts);
```

above code will generate required output and store it on the $result.

Comment: glad to be helpful to you